# google maps: hide labels on the fly + infoBubble masive use + background for streetview panorama,

Tags: styles, maps, infowindow, google-street-view

I am using the google maps and place around 800 markers from a db...

Now I have several question for the fine tuning of that map...

http://camodesign.de/stickermap/geomap.php

1. I am using a styled map - now I'd like to apply a button to hide/show the labels for streets etc... but when I set a style via `"map.setOptions({styles: MyStylesArrayShowLabel});"` that kills all my markers that have a already been placed. Is there a way to set the style on the fly without destroying the markers?
2. I have set a background for the map via "mapOptions" to avoid those ugly grey tiles. Is there a way to do this for the streetview pano too?
3. I had set a  full screen panorama of 100% width and height but the streetview seems only
   to use 60% even when the rest of the screen show grey. Here I don't really have a clue - is it a bug just on my browser?

(+) was trying to use the info bubble instead of the info window for more style
possibilities but the script was hanging and working too long.. after minutes it put out the result correct... seems the bubble had some problems on massive marker use?
had any one similar experiences with it?

Glad for any other suggestions?

(all markers [excluded the home marker/infowindow] are generated from a db via SQL and PHP)